# mock a request entity call for unit test

Tags: java, rest, junit, mockito, resttemplate

i want to mock the request entity and response to test the method on the controller method, this code has been written by another developer and i am supposed to test it using mockito.i'm mocking the controller class

i am trying to mock the request entity value and the respionse entity value , but it's not working and i'm getting a reflection error when i'm trying to debug

```
    public class InquiryController {

private static final Logger log = 
    LoggerFactory.getLogger(InquiryController.class);

@Autowired
private InquiryProperties inquiryProperties;

@Autowired
private InquiryService inquiryService;


@Autowired
RestTemplate restTemplate;

public static int count = 0;


@Bean
private RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}

    @PostMapping(value = "/endCustomer", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }, consumes = {
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
public ResponseEntity<List<EndCustomerDTO>> endCustomer(@RequestBody CustomerInfo customerInfo)
        throws IOException, JSONException {

    log.info("### InquiryController.endCustomer() ===>");
    List<EndCustomerDTO> endCustomerDTOs = null;

    try {

        //RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        RequestEntity<CustomerInfo> body = RequestEntity.post(new URI(inquiryProperties.getEndCustomer()))
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(customerInfo);
        ResponseEntity<List<EndCustomerDTO>> response = restTemplate.exchange(body,
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<EndCustomerDTO>>() {
                });
        endCustomerDTOs = (response != null ? response.getBody() : new ArrayList<EndCustomerDTO>());

    } catch (RestClientException | URISyntaxException e) {
        log.error("InquiryController.endCustomer()" + e.getMessage());
    }

    log.info("### END InquiryController.endCustomer()  ===>");

    if (null == endCustomerDTOs) {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<EndCustomerDTO>>(new ArrayList<EndCustomerDTO>(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<List<EndCustomerDTO>>(endCustomerDTOs, HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

Comment: It looks like you're... trying to mix a configuration and a controller? Replace your field injection with constructor injection and use the `RestOperations` interface instead of `RestTemplate`, and you'll be able to mock the dependency trivially.

Answer (score 0):

It's because instance of `RestTemplate` is not injected through `Spring IOC` when you do the REST call. You need to declare the `getRestTemplate` method of in the component class which is scanned during application startup or in other words during component scan. Thus making `restTemplate` available for `autowire`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you separate the config from the controller as @chrylis suggested, you proceed further like this.

You must be trying to mock the RequestEntity.post method. Note that it is a static method and is mocked a bit differently than the usual public instance methods. For this, you need to use PowerMockito as Mockito won't do.

add the dependency in pom like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

then anotate the test class with `@RunWith`, and `@PrepareForTest` like so:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({RequestEntity.class})
public class TestClass {
}
```

and the mock the post method as so:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(RequestEntity.class);  when(RequestEntity.post(any(URI.class))).thenReturn(getRequestEntityResponseBody());
private RequestEntity< CustomerInfo > getRequestEntityResponseBody(){
 //code
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
CustomerInfo customerInfo = new CustomerInfo();
HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
responseHeaders.set("MyResponseHeader", "MyValue");
RequestEntity<CustomerInfo> customerInfoRequestEntity = new ResponseEntity<CustomerInfo>(customerInfo, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
PowerMockito.mockStatic(RequestEntity.class);
when(RequestEntity.post(any(URI.class))).thenReturn(customerInfoRequestEntity);
```

Comment: can you explain why you hav returned the getRequestEntityResponseBody() and why have you written that method @raviiii1

Comment: It is possible that there are multiple tests for the same method. In that case, this can be reused to return  RequestEntity<CustomerInfo> instead of repeating the creation in each test. It's perfectly fine if you create the objects locally.

Comment: can you show me an exapmle of creating an object /mock object locally. i'm facing issues as it requires url and its a mock test @raviiii1

Comment: @ApurvAdarsh , I have updated the response. As I mentioned before, the creation of `customerInfoRequestEntity ` can be put into a method so that it can be used in other tests.

Comment: can we create request entity object using response entity?
RequestEntity<CustomerInfo> customerInfoRequestEntity = new ResponseEntity<CustomerInfo>(customerInfo, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);

@raviiii1